# Is $L_{P}(R)$ Banach algebra with multiplication defined by convolution?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Is $L_{P}(R)$  with convolution a Banach Algebra?

Comment: $0<p$ and $(f*g)(x)=\int f(x-y)g(y)dy$

Comment: I believe $L_1$ is a Banach algebra.  But in general convolution of two $L_p$ functions may not be in $L_p$.  And is it even defined?

Comment: Using the closed graph theorem and Fourier analysis, one can show that the map $L^2 \to L^2, f\mapsto f\ast g$ with $g \in L^2$ is well-defined (and bounded) if and only if we have $\widehat{g} \in L^\infty$. Since the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F} : L^2 \to L^2$ is bijective, there are many $g \in L^2$ with $\widehat{g} \notin L^\infty$. This shows that for $p=2$, the claim fails. I am pretty sure that the same holds true for any $p \neq 1$.

Comment: It's more of an accident that $L^{1} \star L^{1} \subseteq L^{1}$, and part of that accident is because $L^{1}\star L^{p}\subseteq L^{p}$ for all $1 \le p \le \infty$, and $\|f\star g\|_{p} \le \|f\|_{1}\|g\|_{p}$.